# How to update timeout setting in MongoDB BI Connector

Tags: mysql, mongodb, tableau-api, connector

I am using Tableau BI with MongoDB BI Connector to connect to the MongoDB database server. I have executed one MySQL query from the Tableau, which shows the following error

`Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

For this error, I am trying to increase the **net_read_timeout** property value in the MongoDB BI Connector and as per the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/system-variables/), we can use the following command to update the system variable setting, after connecting the MongoDB BI with the MySQL client.

`mysql --protocol tcp --port 3304 -e "SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout = 100"`

But this command doesn't change the 'net_read_timeout' property value and it reflects the old one

`mysql> show variables like 'net_read_timeout';`

`+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| net_read_timeout | 30    |
+------------------+-------+`

Could anyone please suggest me how to update the system settings of MongoDB BI Connector using the MySQL client? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem recently. It's my solution:

Add the timeout settings(**socketTimeoutMS**, **connectTimeoutMS**) into the connection string(uri) for MongoDB.

They can help you to control the timeout of the connection!

Example:

```
#The configuration file of BI Connector
# ...
mongodb:
  net:
    uri: "<your-mongodb>:27017/?socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000"
# ...
```

I hope this will help!